# Удобная среда разработки для фронтенд-разработчика

Tags: frontend, flask, virtualenv

Добрый день!

Вкратце опишу суть проблемы. Есть сайт, который крутиться в продакшене. 
Используемые технологии - flask, Python, БД (неважно какая). Сервер поднят с использованием apache2 и virtualenv. Проблема заключается в том, что структура папок в проекте flask:

- templates (тут html скрипты, на которые происходят перенаправления с питоновских скриптов)
- static (здесь лежат все css и js файлы)
- питоновские скрипты.

Проблема заключается в том, что фронтэнд-разработчику неудобно отлаживать программы, так как фреймворк flask требует, чтобы html код лежал в templates, в папке static лежали css, а пути к css файлам были указаны через шаблонизаторы, примерно вот так:

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/index.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Только в этом случае на сервере в продакшене все будет нормально и css файлы будут найдены. Разработчик таким образом может либо постоянно менять пути, убирая шаблонизаторы, вот так:

```
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

либо отлаживаться на сервере. Ни то, ни другое неудобно.

Вопрос, как организовать удобную среду разработки для фронтэндера?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть три способа:

1. Верстальщик делает для каждого типа страниц рыбу, бэкендер
   напяливает её на шаблонизатор. При дальнейших правках верстальщик
   правит рыбу, бэкендер правит шаблон. Можно даже организовать процесс
   через накатывание diff-патчей. Плюс в простоте включения верстальщика
   в процесс, минус в дополнительной нагрузке на бэкендера. Хорошо подходит
   для привлечения верстальщиков со стороны.
2. Поднимаете отдельный сервер для разработки. Настраиваете на нём FTP.
   Запускаете на нём нужные проекты, выдаёте права только на шаблоны.
   Запускаете верстальщика по FTP с chroot'ом в каталоге с проектами.
   Минус - нужен дополнительный сервер и понимание языка шаблонизатора
   со стороны верстальщика. Плюс - снижение нагрузки на бэкендера и
   возможность тестировать правки на живом проекте.
3. На комп верстальщика ставится python и git. Верстальщик клонирует
   проект, запускает из корня проекта специально подготовленный батник,
   который активирует виртуальное окружение, ставит зависимости и
   запускает dev-сервер. Требует от верстальщика умения работать с git
   (а других нанимать и не надо), а от бэкендера делать нормальные
   приложения, которые не требуют долгих танцев с бубном для запуска (а других 
   нанимать и не надо).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Можно Вас попросить скинуть источники для того, чтобы выполнить пункты 2 и 3?

Comment: Источники? Вам нужна инструкция по настройке ftp-сервера и виртуального окружения?

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понимаю. Нужно будет настроить на компе фронтэндера виртуальное окружение virtualenv, как на сервере? И чтобы он запускал скрипт питоновский, который его разворачивает. 
Также не очень понимаю, что значит "специально подготовленный бантик"

Comment: Батник, он же пакетный файл - файл с расширением bat или cmd, содержащий набор команд для консоли. Если у дизайнера nix-система, то понадобится shell-файл. И в том и вдругом случае содержимое примерно одинаковое: команда создания виртуального окружения, команда установки зависимостей, команда запуска dev-сервера.